# Unable to disable "...potentially dangerous Request.Path..." in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security

I'm aware that there are a LOT of posts on this topic, however no matter how hard I try (using the detail within such posts) I can't FULLY remove Request Validation from MVC 3.

By way of an ugly, but simple test I have followed these steps:-

1. Open VS and create a new sample MVC3 Internet application.
2. Above each on my Controller Actions I've placed the [ValidateInput(false)] attribute.
3. Edit the root web.config so that `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />` is in the `<system.web />` section.

Whilst this now means that I can submit forms with thing like `<script>` in the field, I still can't work out how to allow Request.Paths such as `http://localhost/MySampleApp/Account/LogOn<script>`.

If I call such a URL I still get **"A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (<)."**

Does anyone know how to REALLY remove all request validation in MVC 3 on .Net 4.0?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may find the [following blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx) useful. My personal advice would be to avoid using such characters in your url paths (unless strictly required) and use query string parameters for transmitting such data to the server:

```
http://localhost/MySampleApp/Account/LogOn?script=%3Cscript%3E
```

Comment: thanks for this - to clarify - we need this fully disabled so that we can run a full Skipfish test of the app... currently it can't test a lot of the 'bad url' attempts because of MVC's built in stuff... I feel a bit uncomfortable relying solely on the .Net implementation of url safety.